# PROBLEMAS CON EL INICIO DE SESION PHP Y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

> *Buenas amigos espero puedan ayudarme tengo un problema con mi inicio de sesion, que a pesar de que ponga los datos correctos me manda el mensaje de que mi user y mi password son incorrectos
> les dejare por acá el  mi user.php me serian de gran ayuda sus respuestas
> .Ademas vi en una pregunta similar que puede que no tenga problemas en mi base de datos si no en el codigo como tal pero no se en que parte.*

```
USER.PHP

<?php  
include_once 'db.php';

class User extends DB
{
    private $nombre;
    private $username;
    
    
    public function usuarioExist($user,$pass)
    {
        $md5pass = md5($pass);

        $query = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE cedula = :user AND clave = :pass');
        $query->execute(['user' => $user, 'pass' => $md5pass]);

        if ($query->rowCount()) {
            return true;
            
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabla_maestra WHERE cedula = user');
         $query->execute(['user'=>$user]);

         foreach ($query as $currentUser){
            $this->nombre = $currentUser['nombre'];
            $this->username = $currentUser['cedula'];
            
         }
    }

    public function getNombre(){
        return $this->nombre;
    }

}


    

?>
```

Comment: Hola glenire, te recomiendo avisarle al `$query->rowCount()` de tu `usuarioExist()` que sea ` > 0` ,  tambien almacena la `$query->execute()` y en esa haz lo del conteo > 0

Answer (score 0):

```
AQUI DEJO MI INDEX.PHP tambien
<?php  
include_once 'includes/user.php';
include_once 'includes/sesion_de_usuario.php';

$userSession = new UserSession();
$user = new User();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
// echo "Hay sesión...";
 
 $user->setUser($userSession->getCurrentUser());
 
}else if (isset($_POST['cedula']) && isset($_POST['clave'])) {
    
     $userForm = $_POST['cedula'];
    $passForm = $_POST['clave'];

     if($user->usuarioExist($userForm,$passForm)){
        echo "usuario validado";
       
        }else{
        echo "nombre de usuario y/o password incorrecto";

        }
}
else{
    //echo "login";
    include_once 'vistas/login.php';
}


?>
```

Comment: No te respondas con más datos, edita la pregunta añadiendo todo lo que consideres necesario para completarla :)